# Centered flex items being cut off if smaller viewport

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a list of divs, such as:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    111111111111111
  </div>
  <div>
    222222222222222
  </div>
  <div>
    333333333333333
  </div>
  <div>
    444444444444444
  </div>
  <div>
    555555555555555
  </div>
</div>
```

On resize, if the container becomes bigger than the viewport, the first/second items from the container will get cut off.

What I really need, ideally with CSS and no mark-up changes, when the viewport is smaller than the container, to have a horizontal scrollbar under the items, and said items to be correctly aligned left, so the first ones won't get cut off.

I know it's the `justify-content: center;` property that center the divs but I need that so divs stay in the center when container is smaller than the viewport.

How could I achieve this? [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hvdf0c62/2/).

Comment: You can use a media query to set justify content when width is greater than something

Comment: Instead of `justify-content: center` use auto margins. https://jsfiddle.net/bz8td64s (Explained in the duplicate.)

Answer (score 1):

I' not exactly sure how you want the elements to behave, but here's the closest thing I could think of:

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: #333;
}

div {
    padding: 10px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    color: yellow;
    background: #666;
    margin: 0 auto; // center within body
    width: fit-content; // center elements within container
    & div {
      border: 1px dashed yellow;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  111111111111
  </div>
  <div>
  2222222222222222222
  </div>
  <div>
  333333333333333
  </div>
  <div>
  444444444444444
  </div>
  <div>
  555555555555555
  </div>
</div>
```

This centers everything within the body element without the use of `justify-content` and does not cut elements out of the viewport.